# Unsatisfiable Constraints Warning not showing in Xcode Debugger

Tags: xcode, debugging, autolayout

I am no longer seeing the "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" warnings in my Xcode console.

I know that I have unsatisfiable auto layout constraints, because I added the `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints` symbolic breakpoint and it is occasionally breaking there.

I'm wondering if there is a specific build setting or something that I accidentally disabled which controls this logging behavior.

Comment: did you enable placeholder i.e remove place holder at run time

Comment: @Maddy I think you are confused as to what my question is. I WANT to see the runtime constraint warnings in the Xcode Console while I'm debugging, and they are not currently showing up for some reason. I don't believe this has anything to do with placeholder constraints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that this was not just affecting warnings from AutoLayout being logged, but rather any API that uses the `os_log` APIs. All logging going thru `os_log` was disabled, preventing these logs from showing up in the Xcode console.

This was due to the `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` environment variable being set to `disabled` in the app's scheme. Once removing this environment variable, all logging returned to normal.